# Undefined method `capitalize' for nil:NilClass, when using .build

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app; hotels and rooms.
When I use this:
`@hotel.rooms.build`,
It gives me this error: `undefined method 'capitalize' for nil:NilClass`.

Here it's the relations,
hotel.rb

```
has_many :rooms
```

room.rb:

```
belongs_to :hotel
```

hotels/show.html.erb:

```
<% @hotel.rooms.each do |room| %>
<tr>
    <td class="goal-project">
        <!-- Avatar -->
        <div data-tooltip ="true" title="<%= @hotel.name.titleize %> | <%= room.room_type.capitalize %> | <%= room.room_number %>">
            <%= room.room_type.slice(0,1).capitalize %>
        </div>
    <div>
        <%= room.room_number %>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>         
<% end %>
```

It works fine, but when I add this form it shows me that error:

```
<!-- Form -->
<%= form_with(model: [ @hotel, @hotel.rooms.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :room_number, type: 'text', placeholder:'enter hotel name' %>
    <%= form.text_field :room_type, type: 'text', class:'form-control form-control-sm', placeholder: "enter city" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `room.room_type` is `nil`. It should most likely be included as a field in your form.

Comment: @MarkMerritt even that, it keeps showing that error.

Comment: Please include your controller action and params. Is `room_type` a permitted param?

Comment: Is the form placed above the list of rooms? Try to place it below that. If that helps I will write an answer how to fix that problem.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak it works with some hotels and shows that error in others 

Comment: @Blue ash Even if the form is not present?